# cannot Delete objects on s3 ceph bucket

Tags: linux, amazon-s3, ceph, s3cmd, object-storage

I have a ceph cluster and running a few s3 bucket on it, 'gitlab-s3-api' user has full permission on everything on  ( users=*;buckets=*;metadata=*;usage=*;zone=* ) but very oddly it cannot delete any file on its own bucket.

```
{
"user_id": "gitlab-s3-api",
"display_name": "Gitlab s3 bucket",
"email": "",
"suspended": 0,
"max_buckets": 1000,
"subusers": [],
"keys": [
    {
        "user": "gitlab-s3-api",
        "access_key": "xxxx",
        "secret_key": "xxxx"
    }
],
"swift_keys": [],
"caps": [
    {
        "type": "buckets",
        "perm": "*"
    },
    {
        "type": "metadata",
        "perm": "*"
    },
    {
        "type": "usage",
        "perm": "*"
    },
    {
        "type": "users",
        "perm": "*"
    },
    {
        "type": "zone",
        "perm": "*"
    }
],
"op_mask": "read, write, delete",
"default_placement": "",
"default_storage_class": "",
"placement_tags": [],
"bucket_quota": {
    "enabled": true,
    "check_on_raw": false,
    "max_size": 32212254720,
    "max_size_kb": 31457280,
    "max_objects": -1
},
"user_quota": {
    "enabled": false,
    "check_on_raw": false,
    "max_size": -1,
    "max_size_kb": 0,
    "max_objects": -1
},
"temp_url_keys": [],
"type": "rgw",
"mfa_ids": []
```

}

I also added DeleteObject policy to the user but it does not work.

```
s3cmd info s3://gitlab
s3://gitlab/ (bucket):
   Location:  default
   Payer:     BucketOwner
   Expiration Rule: none
   Policy:    {
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": {"AWS": ["arn:aws:iam:::user/gitlab-s3-api"]},
    "Action": "s3:DeleteObject",
    "Resource": [
      "arn:aws:s3:::gitlab/*"
    ]
  }]
}

   CORS:      none
   ACL:       Gitlab s3 bucket: FULL_CONTROL
```

Here you can see that I cannot delete the object.

```
s3cmd rm s3://gitlab/ansible.cfg
ERROR: Error parsing xml: Malformed error XML returned from remote server..  ErrorXML: <html><body><h1>403 Forbidden</h1>
Request forbidden by administrative rules.
</body></html>

ERROR: S3 error: 403 (Forbidden)
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that you have the Object Lock (WORM) feature enabled? That would block delete operations.

Comment: I don't know how can I verify that ?
but I can delete all the files when I run the following commands 

"s3cmd rm s3://gitlab/ --recursive --force"

Comment: The problem was in fact with haproxy that was blocking http DELETE Method.